# Thread 3 NullPointerException, character not moving in my code

Tags: java, multithreading, tile

Okay, I'm building an Java Game (RPG) and I'm using a tileset.
Now I wanted to make my character walk tile after tile and build a code, only it returns me an Thread 3 NullPointerException whenever I press the walking buttons..

This is the error it gives me:"

```
Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at net.chosensentinel.dvdv.EntityPlayer.canMove(EntityPlayer.java:152)
    at net.chosensentinel.dvdv.EntityPlayer.move(EntityPlayer.java:48)
    at net.chosensentinel.dvdv.Core.tick(Core.java:70)
    at net.chosensentinel.dvdv.Core.run(Core.java:141)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Every class and method (as far as I know) are being called in the good way.

The code build-up:

Core:

```
package net.chosensentinel.dvdv;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class Core extends Applet implements Runnable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static JFrame frame;

    public static final int res = 1;

    public final int TARGET_FPS = 60;
    public final long OPTIMAL_TIME = 1000000000/TARGET_FPS;
    public static long lastFpsTime = 0;
    public static int fps = 0;
    public static int renderFps = 0;

    public static double oY = 0, oX = 0;
    public static int dir = 0;

    public static boolean moving = false;
    public static boolean run = false;

    private Image screen;

    private ArrayList<Entity> entities = new ArrayList<Entity>();
    private ArrayList<Entity> removeList = new ArrayList<Entity>();

    public static EntityPlayer player;

    public static boolean bW, bS, bA, bD, bE, bSpace, bP;

    public static boolean inGame = true;

    public Level level;

    public static Core core;

    public static Dimension screenSize = new Dimension(700, 560);
    public static Dimension pixel = new Dimension(screenSize.width, screenSize.height);
    public static Dimension Size;

    public static String name = "Dawn - The Chosen Sentinel";

    public Core(){
        setPreferredSize(screenSize);
        addKeyListener(new InputManager());

        initEntities();
    }

    public void tick(double delta){

        frame.pack();

        if(inGame){

            for(int i = 0; i < entities.size(); i++) {
                 Entity entity = (Entity)entities.get(i);
                 entity.move(delta);
            }

            for(int i = 0; i < entities.size(); i++) {
                for(int j = i + 1; j < entities.size(); j++){
                    Entity me = (Entity)entities.get(i);
                    Entity him = (Entity)entities.get(j);
                    if(me.collidesWith(him)){
                        me.collidedWith(him);
                        him.collidedWith(me);
                    }
                }
            }

            entities.remove(removeList);
                removeList.clear();
        }
    }

    public void render(){

        Graphics g = screen.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawRect(0, 0, 800, 800);

        level.render(g, (int)oX, (int)oY, (pixel.width / Tile.size) + 2, (pixel.height / Tile.size) +2);

        for(int i = 0; i < entities.size(); i++) {
             Entity entity = (Entity)entities.get(i);
             entity.render(g);
        }

        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.drawString("FPS: " + renderFps, 600, 530);

        g = this.getGraphics();
        g.drawImage(screen, 0, 0, screenSize.width, screenSize.height, 0, 0, pixel.width, pixel.height, null);
        g.dispose();

    }

    public void removeEntity(Entity entity){
        removeList.add(entity);
    }

    public void initEntities(){
        player = new EntityPlayer(core, (pixel.width / 2) - (Tile.size / 2) + oX, (pixel.height / 2) - (Tile.size / 2) + oY, 32, 32);
        entities.add(player);       
    }

    public void run() {
        screen = createVolatileImage(pixel.width, pixel.height);

        long lastLoopTime = System.nanoTime();

        while(run){

            long now = System. nanoTime();
            long updateLength = now - lastLoopTime;
            lastLoopTime = now;

            double delta = updateLength / (double)OPTIMAL_TIME;
            lastFpsTime += updateLength;
            fps++;

            if(lastFpsTime >= 1000000000){
                renderFps = fps;
                fps = 0;
                lastFpsTime = 0;
            }

            tick(delta);

            render();

            try{
                Thread.sleep((lastLoopTime - System.nanoTime() + OPTIMAL_TIME) / 1000000);
            }catch(Exception e){}
        }
    }

    public void start(){
        requestFocus();

        //define classes
        level = new Level(1);
        new Tile();

        run = true;
        new Thread(this).start();
    }

    public void stop(){
        run = false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        core = new Core();

        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(core);
        frame.pack();

        Size = new Dimension(frame.getWidth(), frame.getHeight());

        frame.setTitle(name);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        core.start();
    }

}
```

EntityPlayer:

```
package net.chosensentinel.dvdv;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

public class EntityPlayer extends Entity{

    public double moveSpeed = 2;

    private static int Rx, Ry;
    public static int tX, tY;

    public static boolean isMoving = false;
    private static int moveDelta = 0;

    private Core CS;

    public int aniFrame = 0;
    public int aniTime = 10;
    public int aniDelta = 0;

    public EntityPlayer(Core cS, double x, double y, int width, int height){
        super(new int[] {0,0}, x, y, width, height);

        Rx = (int)(x - CS.oX);
        Ry = (int)(y - CS.oY);
        CS = cS;
        moveSpeed = 32;
        health = 110;
    }

    @Override
    public void move(double delta){

        aniDelta ++;

        if(aniDelta >= aniTime){
            aniFrame ++;
            aniDelta = 0;
            if(aniFrame > 2){
                aniFrame = 1;
            }
        }

        //up
        if(CS.bW){

            if(canMove(tX, tY - 1)&& !isMoving){
                isMoving = true;
                tY -= 1;
            }
            if(!isMoving){
                CS.bW = false;
            }

            if(isMoving){
                CS.oY += moveSpeed;
                moveDelta += moveSpeed;

                if(moveDelta >= 32){
                    isMoving = false;
                    moveDelta = 0;
                    aniFrame = 0;
                }
            }

        }

        //down
        if(CS.bS){

            if(canMove(tX, tY + 1)&& !isMoving){
                isMoving = true;
                tY += 1;
            }
            if(!isMoving){
                CS.bS = false;
            }

            if(isMoving){
                CS.oY -= moveSpeed;
                moveDelta += moveSpeed;

                if(moveDelta >= 32){
                    isMoving = false;
                    moveDelta = 0;
                    aniFrame = 0;
                }
            }

        }

        //left
        if(CS.bA){

            if(canMove(tX - 1, tY)&& !isMoving){
                isMoving = true;
                tX -= 1;
            }
            if(!isMoving){
                CS.bA = false;
            }

            if(isMoving){
                CS.oX -= moveSpeed;
                moveDelta += moveSpeed;

                if(moveDelta >= 32){
                    isMoving = false;
                    moveDelta = 0;
                    aniFrame = 0;
                }
            }

        }

        //right
        if(CS.bD){

            if(canMove(tX + 1, tY)&& !isMoving){
                isMoving = true;
                tX += 1;
            }
            if(!isMoving){
                CS.bD = false;
            }

            if(isMoving){
                CS.oX += moveSpeed;
                moveDelta += moveSpeed;

                if(moveDelta >= 32){
                    isMoving = false;
                    moveDelta = 0;
                    aniFrame = 0;
                }
            }

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void render(Graphics g){
        super.setImage(new int[]{0,0});

        g.drawImage(image, Rx, Ry, null);
    }

    public boolean canMove(int i, int j){

        if(CS.level.solid[i][j].id == Tile.blank){
            return true;
        }

        return false;

    }

    public void collidedWith(Entity entity) {

    }

}
```

Level:

```
package net.chosensentinel.dvdv;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

import org.newdawn.slick.SlickException;
import org.newdawn.slick.tiled.TiledMap;

public class Level {

    public int width = 100, height = 100;

    public Background[][] bg = new Background[width][height];
    public Solid[][] solid = new Solid[width][height];
    public Item[][] item = new Item[width][height];

    public final String Dpath = "Res/World/Level_";
    public String path = Dpath;

    public TiledMap map = null;

    public Level(int id){
        path = Dpath + Integer.toString(id) + ".tmx";
        System.out.println(path);

        try{
            map = new TiledMap(path, false);
            }catch(SlickException e){
                System.out.println("Error Loading Map!");
            }

        for(int x = 0; x < bg.length; x++){
            for(int y = 0; y < bg[0].length; y++){
                bg[x][y] = new Background(new Rectangle(x * Tile.size, y * Tile.size, Tile.size, Tile.size), Tile.blank);
                solid[x][y] = new Solid(new Rectangle(x * Tile.size, y * Tile.size, Tile.size, Tile.size), Tile.blank);
                item[x][y] = new Item(new Rectangle(x * Tile.size, y * Tile.size, Tile.size, Tile.size), Tile.blank);
            }
        }

        loadWorld();


    }

    public void loadWorld(){
        int background = map.getLayerIndex("background");
        int solids = map.getLayerIndex("collision");
        int items = map.getLayerIndex("object");

        for(int x = 0; x < bg.length; x++){
            for(int y = 0; y < bg[0].length; y++){

                //Background
                if(map.getTileId(x, y, background) == 1){
                    bg[x][y].id = Tile.grass;
                }
                if(map.getTileId(x, y, background) == 2){
                    bg[x][y].id = Tile.road;
                }
                if(map.getTileId(x, y, background) == 3){
                    bg[x][y].id = Tile.leaves;
                }

                //Solids
                if(map.getTileId(x, y, solids) == 64){
                    solid[x][y].id = Tile.grass;
                }

                //Items
                if(map.getTileId(x, y, items) == 129){
                    item[x][y].id = Tile.grass;
                }

            } 
        }
    }


    public void tick(double delta){

    }

    public void render(Graphics g, int camX, int camY, int renX, int renY){
        for (int x = (camX / Tile.size); x < (camX / Tile.size) + renX; x++){
            for (int y = (camY / Tile.size); y < (camY / Tile.size)+ renY; y++){
                if(x >= 0 && y >= 0 && x < width && y < height){
                    bg[x][y].render(g);
                }
            }
        }
    }


}
```

These are every classes etc. what I'm using.

I hope someone can help me out and make my character move (Only the moving, I'll try the animation myself :) )

Comment: Please post the stack trace.

Comment: You really need to boil down your code to a small example.  Right now this is far too long: http://sscce.org/

Comment: Null Pointer Exceptions are generally pretty easy to track down.  All you have to do is go to the line where it says the exception originated, and figure out which object wasn't initialized

Comment: Oke, this is the stack trace: Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at net.chosensentinel.dvdv.EntityPlayer.canMove(EntityPlayer.java:152)
 at net.chosensentinel.dvdv.EntityPlayer.move(EntityPlayer.java:48)
 at net.chosensentinel.dvdv.Core.tick(Core.java:70)
 at net.chosensentinel.dvdv.Core.run(Core.java:141)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: To be honest, I did not know what code you all needed, tell me what I need to delete from the post and I will :)

Comment: Don't use Applet.getGraphics(), this isn't how painting is achieved in Java, instead you should be overriding paint and using repaint to request that the UI be updated. The next question is, why use Applet and why not JApplet? This way you could use JPanel as the bases for your output and get the benefit of the inbuilt double buffering...

Answer (score 0):

This here should be enough to tell you where the exception is coming from

> at net.chosensentinel.dvdv.EntityPlayer.canMove(EntityPlayer.java:152)

So it is obviously this line of code which is causing the problem in your method `EntityPlayer.canMove()`

```
if(CS.level.solid[i][j].id == Tile.blank)
```

This suggests that one of `CS`, `level`, `solid` or the element at that point in the array is null.

Use an IDE to set a breakpoint at that point in the code or add this to find out (crude but will help if you are not familiar with IDE debugging)

```
if(CS == null)
    System.err.println("CS Is null");
else if (CS.level == null)
    System.err.println("CS.level Is null");
else if (CS.level.solid[i][j] == null)
    System.err.println("CS.level.solid["+i+"]["+j+"] Is null");
else if (CS.level.solid[i][j].id == null)
    System.err.println("CS.level.solid["+i+"]["+j+"].id Is null");
else if(CS.level.solid[i][j].id == Tile.blank)
     // your code
```

Then trace back to where these should be initialised

**EDIT**

Ok from your comment and post, I can see this:

In your class `Core` you have

```
public static Core core;
```

In your main method you are creating a `new Core()` and assigning this to the variable `core`

However in your constructor `Core()` you are referencing this variable `core` (in your method `initEntities()`) which has not finished being initialised.

So in main do this

```
core = new Core();
core.initEntities();
```

Comment: Thanks man, will check this out tomorrow and tell you if it worked :D

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out that the problem is with the initialisation in the constructor.

The core is returning null when the code is as follow:

```
public Core(){
        setPreferredSize(screenSize);
        addKeyListener(new InputManager());

        initEntities();
    }
```

If you out command initEntities(); than core is normally running (Not displaying a character or movement) but also not returning null.. My mind is really being blown here..

**EDIT**

Okay, so I added this to my main class:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        core = new Core();
        core.initEntities();
...//More Code
```

and now the constructor is like this:

```
public Core(){
        setPreferredSize(screenSize);
        addKeyListener(new InputManager());
    }
```

**UPDATE**

I can actually move ONE tile now, then this error appears:

```
net.chosensentinel.dvdv.Core[panel0,0,0,0x0,invalid,layout=java.awt.FlowLayout]
    Res/World/Level_1.tmx
    Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
        at net.chosensentinel.dvdv.EntityPlayer.canMove(EntityPlayer.java:148)
        at net.chosensentinel.dvdv.EntityPlayer.move(EntityPlayer.java:119)
        at net.chosensentinel.dvdv.Core.tick(Core.java:67)
        at net.chosensentinel.dvdv.Core.run(Core.java:138)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

This is what I changed:

```
@Override
public void move(double delta){

    aniDelta ++;

    if(aniDelta >= aniTime){
        aniFrame ++;
        aniDelta = 0;
        if(aniFrame > 2){
            aniFrame = 1;
        }
    }

    //up
    if(Core.bW){

        if(canMove(tX, tY + 1)&& !isMoving){
            isMoving = true;
            tY -= 1;
        }
        if(!isMoving){
            Core.bW = false;
        }

        if(isMoving){
            Core.oY -= moveSpeed;
            moveDelta += moveSpeed;

            if(moveDelta >= 32){
                isMoving = false;
                moveDelta = 0;
                aniFrame = 0;
            }
        }

    }

    //down
    if(Core.bS){

        if(canMove(tX, tY + 1)&& !isMoving){
            isMoving = true;
            tY -= 1;
        }
        if(!isMoving){
            Core.bS = false;
        }

        if(isMoving){
            Core.oY += moveSpeed;
            moveDelta += moveSpeed;

            if(moveDelta >= 32){
                isMoving = false;
                moveDelta = 0;
                aniFrame = 0;
            }
        }

    }

    //left
    if(Core.bA){

        if(canMove(tX + 1, tY)&& !isMoving){
            isMoving = true;
            tX -= 1;
        }
        if(!isMoving){
            Core.bA = false;
        }

        if(isMoving){
            Core.oX -= moveSpeed;
            moveDelta += moveSpeed;

            if(moveDelta >= 32){
                isMoving = false;
                moveDelta = 0;
                aniFrame = 0;
            }
        }

    }

    //right
    if(Core.bD){

        if(canMove(tX + 1, tY)&& !isMoving){
            isMoving = true;
            tX -= 1;
        }
        if(!isMoving){
            Core.bD = false;
        }

        if(isMoving){
            Core.oX += moveSpeed;
            moveDelta += moveSpeed;

            if(moveDelta >= 32){
                isMoving = false;
                moveDelta = 0;
                aniFrame = 0;
            }
        }

    }

}
```